# Symfony assign multiple variable in a single statement

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to initialize multiple variables using a single statement in twig page. How I can do it? Below is my code and it looks horrible.

```
{% set t1Tot = 0 %}
{% set t2Tot = 0 %}
{% set t3Tot = 0 %}
{% set c1Tot = 0 %}
{% set c2Tot = 0 %}
{% set c3Tot = 0 %}
{% set o1Tot = 0 %}
{% set o2Tot = 0 %}
{% set o3Tot = 0 %}
{% set grandTot = 0 %}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can assign multiple variables in single statement as per [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html)

```
{% set foo, bar = 'foo', 'bar' %}

{% set t1Tot,t2Tot,t3Tot   = 0,0,0 /* ... */ %}
```